# How can I get the page size of a Postgres database?

Tags: postgresql

Is there some way to select the page size of a Postgres database?

I know that the page size is usually 8K. I also read [this email thread from 2003](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/4670.1059514957%40sss.pgh.pa.us). I don't know that `pg_controldata` will work as I don't have access to the filesystem that the database is hosted on.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you don't have access to [`pg_controldata`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgcontroldata.html) ...

There is a simple way:

```
test=# SELECT current_setting('block_size');
 current_setting
-----------------
 8192
```

[The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-preset.html#GUC-BLOCK-SIZE)

> The following “parameters” are read-only, and are determined when
>   PostgreSQL is compiled or when it is installed. [...]
>
> `block_size` (`integer`)
>
> Reports the size of a disk block. It is determined by the value of `BLCKSZ` when building the server. The default value is 8192 bytes. The
>   meaning of some configuration variables (such as [shared_buffers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-resource.html#GUC-SHARED-BUFFERS)) is
>   influenced by `block_size`. See [Section 19.4](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-resource.html) for information.

#### To verify

Create a dummy table with only 1 small row: one data page is allocated. Then check the size of [the "main" relation fork with `pg_relation_size()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-DBSIZE)

```
test=# CREATE TEMP TABLE foo AS SELECT 1 AS id;
SELECT 1
test=# SELECT pg_size_pretty(pg_relation_size('pg_temp.foo'));
 pg_size_pretty
----------------
 8192 bytes
(1 row)
```

So the page size is 8 kB, which is hardly surprising like you mentioned. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/storage-page-layout.html)

> Every table and index is stored as an array of pages of a fixed size (usually 8 kB, although a different page size can be selected when compiling the server).

Comment: +1 - but just as a matter of interest, why would one compile the server with a different page size?

Comment: Never done this myself, but I imagine if you have large rows (that cannot be "toasted") it might save a bit of overhead. Not sure it would be worth the trouble.

Comment: @Vérace  A btree index entry is limited to about 1/3 of the block size.  That could be one motivation to increase it.  You might also hope to get better performance, but I've never seen that pan out myself.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter - Thanks for that Erwin. You might be interested in a bonus that I'm offering [Postgresql related](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/239958/wordcount-in-a-field-all-and-unique-is-there-a-more-elegant-optimal-way) - it should be right up your alley!

Comment: One plausible reason is if you want to match underlying storage block size (and not vice versa, for one reason or another). Like RAID stripe size, or ZFS recordsize. Also compression ratio might increase, at least for indexes, if data is sorted in larger chunks before compression.